# Find and replace for vertex groups

Tags: python, rigging, armature, vertex-groups

I'm working on a rigify model and for some reason the vertex group names did not change with the bone names. I didn't realize this until too late and now I need to remove the prefix "bip_" from all the groups as well as change "_l" and "_r" to ".L" and .R" respectively. Batch rename does not feature the option to batch rename vertex groups. Is there an easy way to automatically change the names with a python script possibly?